# Spree routes not available in extension's dummy application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, routes, spree

I'm upgrading an Extension which was originally built for Spree 1.2.5 to use Spree 2.0.4.

My problem is the wrapper application at *test/dummy* doesn't have spree's routes available.

If I run `$ rake routes` inside it, only those added by the extension are presented,
because its *config/routes.rb* file does have **Spree::Core::Engine.routes** mounted.

Has anybody got a catch what could cause this?

Comment: at first I thought it was because the extension used dummier instead of now built-in  `rake test_app`, but I reproduced the issue using the latter

Comment: also, if I comment out my extension's *config/routes.rb*, no routes are available at all.

so, apparently my routes are correctly mounted, but the rest of spree's routes were never there...

could it need some kind of reload?

Comment: did you try using a "full engine"? http://www.astjohn.ca/2011/08/06/rails-31-engines-mountable-or-full-part-1

Comment: in this case the extension is generated using `spree extension` command, which does use a `--full` plugin indeed.
it is also more or less `--mountable`, by the way, since it uses *namespace isolation*, for eg., but doesn't have an **application_controller.rb** and uses a different structure for asset manifest files, etc

Comment: Is the extension that you're trying to upgrade open source?  If so, could you provide a link to it?

Comment: it is: https://github.com/Numerico/spree_variant_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I just dropped **dummier** gem & moved on to use spree's own `rake test_app` task for this.

*I think the root issue was I wasn't including **spree_auth_devise** in my Gemfile, and that's where spree extensions depend on **spree_frontend** (see picture).*

[image]

As the gem wasn't there, that engine was never mounted. This happened even in the dummy app generated by `test_app`, until I added

```
# Provides basic authentication functionality for testing parts of your engine 
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-0-stable'
```

to my *Gemfile*

Truth is I wasn't including that on purpose. I'm not adding anything login-related...
I wonder if it is not misleading to make that dependency **implicit**.

Here's the relevant *commit* https://github.com/Numerico/spree_variant_options/commit/5152c3c603bf812d7c357bf6a1e89b06b888a0d2